# Restricting the scope of the LookupSymbols method in the Roslyn Semantic Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I'm implementing my own diagnostic analyzer in Roslyn. My goal is to identify identifiers that are too similar to others and report those instances.

I want to make sure that I only emit warnings if the conflicting identifiers are within the same scope. That is, I only warn that an identifier X is similar to Y if from the place where Y is declared, X can also be referred to.

My current approach is to use the LookupSymbols method. Using the syntax node that contains the identifier, I can find its location in the source and find all symbols in scope. I then only look at the identifiers of those symbols.

However, I'm afraid that this method is very expensive, especially if I do it for every identifier in a given source file. Is there a way to make this process cheaper, for instance, by limiting the scope of the LookupSymbols method to the current document?

This code illustrates what I'm doing:

```
private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var node = context.Node;
    var position = node.SpanStart;
    var symbolsInScope = context.SemanticModel.LookupSymbols(position);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LookupSymbols doesn't have a option to filter to the same file. But it'd be very easy to make a syntax walker that could walk a file and collect the names that way. In other words, just put together the information you need with the pieces you have.